# When RewriteEngine On & directory is password protected by .htaccess, the user can hit cancel & see my content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Bit of a weird scenario here and I think it's due to the host's settings (this particular site is on a shared server) and having recently switched hosts, this didn't happen on the previous host.

When `RewriteEngine On` & directory is password protected by .htaccess, the user can hit cancel & see the html of the index -- no stylesheet or images load.

If I set `RewriteEngine Off` - .htaccess protects the directory as it should.

Is there some sort of flag I can set in htaccess to prevent the mod_rewrite from obfuscating the htaccess protection?

.htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/home/user/.htpasswds/public_html/example.com/passwd"
require valid-user
AuthName "Restricted"

RewriteEngine Off

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

 RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?route=common/home [L]
#numerous rules similar to the above
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your rule could be matching the sub-request the gets the 403 document. Are you sure the images/style for that 403 aren't just the same broken 403? Without your `.htaccess`, no one's going to be able to really help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your last rule:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?_route_=$0 [NS,DPI,L,QSA]
```

The string that's matched against rule patterns doesn't contain the query delimiter, so the above is equivalent.

Comment: Still gives the same behavior; no password prompt and the html loads